# Cannot insert into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I am getting the error:

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'desc'.

Can anyone please help me what is the problem ?

```
if (IsPost && Validation.IsValid())
{
    name = Request.Form["name"];
    price = Request.Form["price"];
    desc = Request.Form["desc"];

    var db = Database.Open("mystring");
    var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO CarBike (name,image,price,desc,date,userid) VALUES(@0,@1,@2,@3,@4,@5)";
    db.Execute(insertCommand, name, image, price, desc, date, userid);
    Response.Redirect("~/Members");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that *desc* is a keyword in SQL, so you need to write that column using square brackets:

```
var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO CarBike (name,image,price,[desc],date,userid) VALUES(@0,@1,@2,@3,@4,@5)";
```